# No funciona el validate en laravel en api

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-10

Buen día tengo un inconveniente con laravel. Estoy haciendo una api con la version 10.x de laravel. Graba los datos normal pero a la hora de validar los datos no me esta mostrando los errores. Así estaría el proyecto hasta ahora.

Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        //validación de los datos
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);    
        //alta del usuario
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();
        //respuesta
        /* return response()->json([
            "message" => "Alta exitosa"
        ]); */
        return response($user, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
    public function login(Request $request){

    }
    public function userProfile(Request $request){

    }
    public function logout(){

    }
    public function allUsers(Request $request){

    }
}
```

Este sale por la ruta api :

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\api\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

El modelo:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```

En postman mando la solicitud así:
[image: img referencia]

Y me sale esto, en vez de que me salga el error que faltan datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería de salir el error que el campo name esta vacío, y no solo es ese campo, en general con cualquier error. Estoy guiandome de la documentacion y antes lo he hecho así. No se si sea algo de la version, pero ya revise toda la documentacion y no dice nada sobre ese tema en especifico. Ya monte el proyecto 3 veces y en las tres veces el mismo error.

Comment: Prueba poniendo `Accept: application/json` en los headers de postman

Comment: si era eso claro no verifique los header del postman Gracias.